# i need paypal soap value to redirect checkout page

Tags: php

```
<form method="post" action="https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp">
        <input type="hidden" name="USER" value="ram.fobess_api1.gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="PWD" value="1395047802">
        <input type="hidden" name="SIGNATURE" value="A5sBito4n5-BXuCBOs3GVB4hSd3CAMOtrfhtX7gYJ8IRalRwwoRJEyJQ">
        <input type="hidden" name="VERSION" value="98.0">
        <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION"
        <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE "
            value="USD">
        <input name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" value="19.95">
        <input type="hidden" name="RETURNURL"
            value="https://www.YourReturnURL.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="CANCELURL" value="https://www.YourReturnURL.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="TOKEN"
            value="EC-1CX69969Y0329883A">
    <input type="submit" name="METHOD" value="GetExpressCheckoutDetails"> 
        <!--  <input type="submit" name="METHOD" value="SetExpressCheckout"> -->

    </form>
```

this is my code i want this value post as redirect to checkout page... how..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
$desc = 'hidsdsf';//set to the order description to be appear on the PayPal website;
$orderno = '1001';//set to unique order number;
$nettotal = '12';//set to productTotal + shipmentFee + tax;
$_SESSION["ss_last_orderno"] = $orderno;

//Save order information to database using the unique order number with status set as Pending...


$url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"; //Test
//$url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"; //Live
//$ppAcc = "ram.fobess@gmail.com"; //PayPal account email
$ppAcc = "ram.fobess@outlook.com"; //PayPal account email
$cancelURL = "http://localhost/final/paypal_cancel.php";
//$returnURL = "http://localhost/final/return.php";
$returnURL = "http://localhost/final/lunch.php";
//$notiesURL = "http://localhost/final/returnfinal.php"; "<input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='$notiesURL'>\n".

$buffer =
"<form action='$url' method='post' name='frmPayPal'>\n".
"<input type='hidden' name='business' value='$ppAcc'>\n".
"<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>\n".
"<input type='hidden' display='1' value='permonth'>\n".
"<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='$desc'>\n".
"<input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='$orderno'>\n".
"<input type='hidden' name='amount' alt='per month' value='$nettotal'>\n".
"<input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>\n".
"<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>\n".
"<input type='hidden' name='handling' value='0'>\n".
"<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='$cancelURL'>\n".
"<input type='hidden' name='return' value='$returnURL'>\n".

"</form>\n".
"<script language='javascript'>document.frmPayPal.submit();</script>\n";

echo($buffer);
?>
```

return page

> `/*         Part - 3 */        $parameter_value_array = explode("\n", $ipnresult);         $value_array =array();      foreach`
>
>   
>   ($parameter_value_array as $key=>$value) {            $key_values =
>   explode("=", $value);             $value_array[$key_values[0]] =
>   $key_values[1];       }
>
> ```
>   if(array_key_exists("status", $value_array) &&
> ```
>
> $value_array['status'] == 'SUCCESS') {
>                  echo utf8_decode(urldecode($value_array['item_name']));        echo '
> ';       echo utf8_decode(urldecode($value_array['quantity']));
>         echo '
> ';       echo
>   utf8_decode(urldecode($value_array['payer_email']));      echo '
> '; 
>                 foreach($value_array as $key=>$nm){             //$ram .= print_r($value_array);            $ram .= $key .' =
>   '.utf8_decode(urldecode($nm))."
> ";            }       }
>                 echo $ram;
>                 ?>

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your checkout page URL here:

```
<input type="hidden" name="RETURNURL" value="https://www.YourReturnURL.com">
```

in the value part give you URL.